# Why is my program giving an incorrect output in certain cases?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have made an implementation of the Euclidean Algorithm in Java to find the Greatest Common Divisor (GCD) of two given numbers.

For the most part, my program works fine, I have tested it with a few random sets of numbers, although, I have found in one case (that I know of) that it's giving an incorrect output, which is for the following combination of numbers:

> Enter integer a: 8965
> Enter integer b: 55

The output of the program should be 55, although this is not the case. The out given is as follows:

> gcd = 1
> Execution time: 0.005747ms.

I'm not sure why this particular combination of numbers is causing a problem, as it works fine for other numbers, for example, here is the results for a different set of numbers:

> Enter integer a: 15000
>
> Enter integer b: 5325
>
> gcd = 75
>
> Execution time: 0.007389ms.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class EuclideanAlgorithm {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        int a, b;
        try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);) {
            System.out.print("Enter integer a: ");
            a = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter integer b: ");
            b = sc.nextInt();
        }
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        int answer = EuclideanAlgorithm(a, b);
        long stop = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("gcd = " + answer);
        System.out.println("Execution time: " + ((stop - start) / 1e+6) + "ms.");
        
    }
    
    public EuclideanAlgorithm() {}; //Suppress default constructor
    
    private static int EuclideanAlgorithm(int a, int b) {
        if ( (a == 0) || (b == 0)) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (b > a) {
            int temp = a;
            a = b;
            b = temp;
        }
        int gcd = 1;
        while(gcd != 0) {
            if( (a % b) == 0) {
                break;
            }
            gcd = a % b;
            a  = b;
            b = gcd;
        }
        return gcd;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Trobbins My debugger doesn't show any warnings or errors, as I said, the program works for the most part, just for certain combinations of numbers, it gives an incorrect output, and I can't see why...

Comment: When `a` is divisible by `b`, you break immediately and leave `gdc` at its initial value. Perhaps you need to initialise `gdc` to `b`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever one of your numbers `a`, `b` is a multiple of the other, then your `if` condition will cause a `break` and `1` will be returned, which is incorrect.  But the rest of the algorithm is incorrect also.

According to the pseudocode for the [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations):

```
function gcd(a, b)
while b ≠ 0
   t := b
   b := a mod b
   a := t
return a
```

You need to check if `b` is not `0`, not the gcd.  You'll need to modify your code to match this algorithm; your code is not currently matching this algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the if condition inside this while loop

```
int gcd = 1;
while(gcd != 0) {
    if( (a % b) == 0) {
        break;
    }
    gcd = a % b;
    a  = b;
    b = gcd;
}
```

So, in case a % b = 0 at the beginning -> result is always equaled to 1.

You need to handle that case separately.

```
int gcd = b;
while(a % b != 0){
   gcd = a % b;
   a = b;
   b = gcd;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy 55 divides 8965 that means you programm breaks in the first line and returns your initial value which is 1.

Instead something like this could help.

```
int gcd = 1;
if( (a % b) == 0) {
   return b;
}
while(gcd != 0) {
    if( (a % b) == 0) {
        break;
    }
    gcd = a % b;
    a  = b;
    b = gcd;
}
```